# Vector and engraving help

Tags: vector, software-recommendation, corel-draw

I'm new to working with inkscape and Corel Draw.

I will engrave the exported files using a CnC controlled machine.

The issue I am having: using Corel's contour tool, it's fine. It fills the vector shape with path lines for engraving etc, but it's also in an island type pattern, where as a side to side vector path infill pattern is far more effective and better for engraving.

Does anyone have a specific method for doing this, or software perhaps that they could lead me to? I have included 2 photos for examples of the 2 different styles of inside filling/path's.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please consider that inkscape is not the right tool for this.

Comment: OK guys to clarify, the second image is what I would like to be able to do, not the contoured image like in the first. so the question is, how to fill shapes/images after turning them into curves with a side to side type fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can consider an alternative method to accomplish your objective, take a look at the [video a YouTuber created](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctM2fCrfom0) for engraving/milling a pokemon ball.

Part two is the link, part one shows the creator making the design in Inkscape.

In part two, he uses an online resource known as [makercam](http://www.makercam.com/) to convert his drawing to a series of paths for his engraving device, a [Maslow CNC Router](http://www.maslowcnc.com/), an interesting machine in its own right.

There is a bit of explanation for configuring the makercam to meet his requirements. If your engraver is a mechanical device and supports G-code, you will likely have good results. If it does not support G-code, it would be useful to know this. Many engraving devices, including laser cutters/engravers often provide software to cover the tool paths automatically.

You can find many tutorial videos covering [makercam on the YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=makercam).

I think you might be adding an unnecessary step by attempting to create the tool paths manually.

One could also purchase a retail product, such as [Vectric's Cut2D](http://www.vectric.com/products/cut2d.html) which will also import your shape files and create tool paths.

With respect to the final product, the parallel line method will create saw-tooth or scalloped edges rather than a smooth outline. This is why you'll find the "island" type of cutting sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your time Fred and knowledge! very great-full and will be looking into everything you said.